# Get changing output python subprocess

Tags: python

I am looking for a solution to read "changing"/"moving" outputs in python subprocesses (cURL to be specific). For some reasons, I can not use pycurl, I just have the binary.

Obviously, this kind of code is not going to work :

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ntpq", "-p"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Do you have an idea on what I can do to retrieve curl data (speed, ETA,...) ?

Comment: Is all you really want the curl data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` to get asnyc output. 
e.g.:

```
$ tree
.
├── async_output.py
└── changing_output.sh
```

py code:

```
$ cat async_output.py 
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

#proc = Popen(['curl', 'http://www.baidu.com'], stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
proc = Popen(['changing_output.sh'], stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
while proc.poll() == None:
    import fcntl
    import os
    import select
    fcntl.fcntl(
            proc.stdout.fileno(),
            fcntl.F_SETFL,
            fcntl.fcntl(proc.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK,
            )

    fcntl.fcntl(
            proc.stderr.fileno(),
            fcntl.F_SETFL,
            fcntl.fcntl(proc.stderr.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK,
            )

    while proc.poll() == None:
        readx = select.select([proc.stdout.fileno()], [], [], 0.1)[0]
        readx_err = select.select([proc.stderr.fileno()], [], [], 0.1)[0]
        if readx:
            chunk = proc.stdout.read()
            print chunk,
        elif readx_err:
            chunk = proc.stderr.read()
            print chunk,
        else:
            break
proc.wait()
```

sh code:

```
$ cat changing_output.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in `seq 1 10`; do
  echo $i
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I missed the fact that you were looking for the speed data.  You can obviously calculate this yourself, since you can call `time.time()` before and after the transfer, and you can calculate the number of bytes transferred.  Like this:

```
import subprocess
import time

start_time = time.time()
out = subprocess.check_output([
    'curl', '--silent', 'http://google.com/'])
end_time = time.time()
bytes_per_sec = len(out)/(end_time-start_time)
```

Comment: If you notice in his question, he wants the speed data.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that.  In that case, I would do exactly what I have in this code, but call `time.time()` before and after and calculate the speed myself.

Comment: Indeed, if only I could type as fast as you I could have saved you an extra comment!